# sql select similar movies based on categories match frequency

Tags: mysql, sql

hi there i hope you are good guys 
i want to select similar movies based on movie categories 
so i have this tables in my database

```
table movies :id,title,......,date
table movie_categories : id,id_movie,id_category
table categories : id,category
```

where category is simply : action,drama,.....
i'm little noob noob in sql queries so i hope someone can help me 
 and i've tried this so far

```
SELECT m.*,COUNT(mc.*) AS cat_frequency 
FROM movies m,movie_categories mc 
WHERE mc.id_category IN (SELECT c.id_category FROM movie_categories c WHERE id_movie = 1)
ORDER BY cat_frequency
```

where 1 is the id of the movie that user currently viewing
**the expected result** is all movie data and with categories match frequency
for exemple let's say current watched movie have categories : **action,fantastic,drama** 
so the movies that have the same categories (100% : have same categories) will be first in order , and then the movies that (66.66% : only 2 categories are matched) and so on ....
**note : i can do it in php but i want to do it with sql**

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Looks like you need a `group by` to make the count work

Comment: provide some data sample and expected result

Comment: i've added some more details check it again please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know the current movie categories

```
 SELECT c.id_category 
 FROM movie_categories c 
 WHERE id_movie = 1
```

Then you need check how many categories match each movies

```
SELECT m.id, COUNT(*) AS cat_frequency 
FROM movies m
JOIN movie_categories mc ON m.id = mc.id_movie   
WHERE mc.id_category IN ( SELECT c.id_category 
                          FROM movie_categories c 
                          WHERE c.id_movie = 1 )
GROUP BY m.id
```

Now you have the matching number of cat, you join both to sort by that atribute

```
SELECT m.*
FROM movies m
JOIN (
        SELECT m.id, COUNT(*) AS cat_frequency 
        FROM movies m
        JOIN movie_categories mc ON m.id = mc.id_movie    
        WHERE mc.id_category IN ( SELECT c.id_category 
                                  FROM movie_categories c 
                                  WHERE c.id_movie = 1 )
        GROUP BY m.id
     ) f
  ON m.id = f.movie_id
WHERE m.id <> 1 -- you probably dont want show the current movie.
ORDER BY f.cat_frequency DESC
```

Comment: you missed typing in ( m.movie_id = f.movie.id) you wanted to type m.movie_id = f.movie_id ?

Comment: and the second query is work perfectly but i need to eliminate the current movie

Comment: Yes, was a typo. And doesnt the `where` clause remove the current movie? Not sure what you mean

Comment: it worked for me perfectly , thank you so much bro , but you forgot DESC and you miss typed as i said , ill add what worked for me

Comment: Well you also forgot DESC in your query I just copy from there. Also remove an extra ORDER BY was floating around

Comment: i just learned how to build sql queries from your perfect step by step guide, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need such a query :

```
SELECT m.title, c.id_category,COUNT(*) AS cat_frequency 
  FROM movies m
  JOIN movie_categories mc ON m.id = mc.id_movie
  JOIN categories c ON c.id_category = mc.id_category
 GROUP BY c.id_category
 ORDER BY cat_frequency DESC;
```

Comment: That only bring you movie = 1 not the similar movies

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, of course, didn't consider, thanks.

Comment: thanks for answer, but as he said it bring me the movie = 1